# C26434 Function xxx hides a non-virtual function

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, code-inspection

Take this simple code:

```
void CRestoreSettingsDlg::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
    CResizingDialog::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);

    m_gridBackupLog.ExpandLastColumn();
}
```

Why is it being flagged?

[image]

> C26434 Function `'CRestoreSettingsDlg::OnSize'` hides a non-virtual function `'CRestoreDialogDlg::OnSize'`.

As you can see, I call the base class method.

---

### Declarations and Definitions

- `CRestoreSettingsDlg`:

```
public:
    afx_msg void OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy);

void CRestoreSettingsDlg::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
    CResizingDialog::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);

    m_gridBackupLog.ExpandLastColumn();
}
```

- `CResizingDialog`:

```
public:
    afx_msg void OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy);

void CResizingDialog::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
    CDialogEx::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);

    Invalidate(TRUE);
}
```

- The boilerplate base class (`afxwin.h`) appears to have:

```
protected:
    afx_msg void OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy);

_AFXWIN_INLINE void CWnd::OnSize(UINT, int, int)
    { Default(); }
```

---

### Inheritance

1. `class CRestoreSettingsDlg : public CResizingDialog`
2. `class CResizingDialog : public CDialogEx`

Comment: The question may actually be why you don't see that 'error message' more often? For example, I presume your `CResizingDialog::OnSize()` function is also 'hiding' the base class function (presumably, `CWnd::OnSize()`). And this would go for a number of MFC message-handler 'overrides' for non-virtual functions (those with the `afx_msg` attribute, which is generally defined as empty).

Comment: Maybe show us the *exact* definitions/declarations of the various `OnSize()` member functions, to see if there's a weird but subtle difference in their signatures.

Comment: This link might be interesting: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26434. Also show us the exact declarations of `CResizingDialog::OnSize` and `CRestoreSettingsDlg::OnSize` as they appear in the .h files.

Comment: @AdrianMole Question updated.

Comment: I can't reproduce this even with the MS sample fom the link I posted in my previous comment. Can you reproduce it with this code? Do you have some special compiler flags? Which compiler do you use?

Comment: @Jabberwocky I use Visual Studio 2019 Latest release. If there is any specific settings you need to know I will provide.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/using-the-cpp-core-guidelines-checkers?view=msvc-160 to enable these warnings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[C26434 warning documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26434?view=msvc-160) links to [C.128 C++ Core Guidelines Rule](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rh-override). It explains that to enforce correct usage of virtual functions, non-virtual function hiding should produce a warning.

However, with MFC message maps, you have to name your message handler as specified in macro, `OnSize` in this case, and, since message handlers already dispatched by a virtual function (that is hidden in `*_MESSAGE_MAP()` macros), message handler by themselves don't have to be virtual.

So it may be seen as a false alarm. Or maybe seen as violation of the above mentioned C.128 rule by MFC itself. No surprise - MFC is decades older than these guidelines.

So I guess you can go ahead and suppress it for all `afx_msg` functions. Maybe redefine `afx_msg` to include `__pragma(warning(suppress(...)))`, or just have suppression around `afx_msg` block.

---

Some options for suppression ([Godbolt's compiler explorer demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1GrrrfE4M)):

```
#define afx_msg // this is normally defined by MFC

struct base
{
    afx_msg void OnSize(){}
};


struct derived1 : base
{
    afx_msg void OnSize() {} // produces C26434
};

// Suppression by adding some code:

struct derived2 : base
{
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable:26434)
    afx_msg void OnSize() {} 
#pragma warning(pop)
};

struct derived3 : base
{
    [[gsl::suppress(c.128)]] afx_msg void OnSize() {}
};


// Suppression by redefining MFC macro -- dirty but less intrusive:

#undef afx_msg
#define afx_msg __pragma(warning(suppress:26434))


struct derived4 : base
{
    afx_msg void OnSize() {} 
};


#undef afx_msg
#define afx_msg [[gsl::suppress(c.128)]]


struct derived5 : base
{
    afx_msg void OnSize() {}
};
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there examples of how to do these various suppressing approaches?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle, added examples